# Is it possible in react-big-calendar to display the week and month vertically?

Tags: reactjs, scheduled-tasks, react-big-calendar

I'm trying to implement a custom calendar for employees' task management system using react-big-calendar, I want the week/month days to be displayed vertically and the resources horizontally with several features.
So, I was wondering if that is possible, using react-big-calendar?